# .net StackFrame and current line/column

Tags: c#, .net, assert, stack-frame

I wrote a method Assert():

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
internal static void Assert(bool condition)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        var message =
                "Line:" + (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)).GetFileLineNumber() + "\r\n" +
                "Column:" + (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)).GetFileColumnNumber() + "\r\n" +
                "Where:" + (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)).GetMethod().Name;
            Log("ASSERTION", message);
        }
    }
```

Why do I have both line and column being equal to 0, when triggered? It supposed to be the place where Debug.Assert(false) is called.

Regards,

Comment: why are you writing your own assert method?

Comment: Because I have to write to my own log system. Since the assembly is SQLCLR trigger, the output is stored in a special table.

Comment: Do you have your .pdb in the same folder as the .exe/.dll? Are you using an old version of mono?

Comment: I'm not sure where the assembly is located at all, since it's re-created with CREATE ASSEMBLY command from T-SQL. Anyway I'd like to avoid dependencies from pdb or whatever... configuration files with DefaultTraceListener settings, maybe... so, I've just rewrote Assert() on my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [`StackFrame(int, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deysbxxw.aspx) overload and specify `true` as the second argument. It looks like just the `StackFrame(int)` overload doesn't capture source information.

Sample code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
internal static void Assert(bool condition)
{
    if (!condition)
    {
        StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1, true);
        var message = string.Format("Line: {0}\r\nColumn: {1}\r\nWhere:{2}",
                                    frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                                    frame.GetFileColumnNumber(),
                                    frame.GetMethod().Name);
        Log("ASSERTION", message);
    }
}
```

(Looking at your comments by the way, you *will* need the PDB files. That's where the debug information is stored. It's not at all clear to me whether this will work in a SQLCLR trigger, to be honest. The above works for me in a console app, but that's all I can say...)

Comment: Hm... If I need PDB, why does frame.GetMethod().Name work even in Release configuration and optimization on? (I'd checked it earlier). BTW, it works for new StackFrame(1) too, when line/column are 0.

Comment: @noober: The method name is part of the normal metadata making up a .NET assembly - it's not debug information.

Comment: So I cannot make my Assert() working without debug information. OK... Will output parent method only.